# How do I define an array of objects with the same parent type?

Tags: angular, typescript, casting

When the Toolage object displays its list of objects of type ToolButtonComponent, they're undefined. What am I doing wrong here?

```
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tool-button',
  templateUrl: './tool-button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tool-button.component.css']
})
export class ToolButtonComponent implements OnInit {

  public constructor(theTile:string) {
  }


  ngOnInit() {
  }

}

export class FunButtonComponent extends ToolButtonComponent implements OnInit {



  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
export class CoolButtonComponent extends ToolButtonComponent implements OnInit {


  ngOnInit() {
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-toolage',
  template: `
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <h2>Toolage</h2>
  <p>Tools:</p>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let tool of tools">
      {{ tool.theTile }}
    </li>
  </ul>
`
})
export class Toolage {
  private tools: ToolButtonComponent[] = [ 
      new ToolButtonComponent("tool button"), 
      new FunButtonComponent('fun button'), 
      new CoolButtonComponent("fa-eraser")
    ];

  constructor() { }

  getTools() : ToolButtonComponent[] {
    return this.tools;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm new to angular and typescript but I think the main issue is that `theTile` parameter for `ToolButtonComponent`'s constructor doesn't do anything. What you want to do is assign it to a property on `ToolButtonComponent` like in the following:

```
export class ToolButtonComponent implements OnInit {

    public theTile:string;

    public constructor(theTile:string) {

        this.theTile = theTile;

    }// end constructor

}// end class
```

The classes `FunButtonComponent` and `CoolButtonComponent` will inherit this property. Now you call `super()` to parse parameter `theTile` from their constructor to the parent constructor which will automatically set their inherited property to the value of that parameter, like in the following:

```
export class FunButtonComponent extends ToolButtonComponent {

    public constructor(theTile:string) {

        super(theTile);

    }// end constructor

}// end class


export class CoolButtonComponent extends ToolButtonComponent {

    public constructor(theTile:string) {

        super(theTile);

    }// end constructor

}// end class
```

It all should look something like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <app-toolage></app-toolage>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {}


@Component({
    selector: 'app-toolage',
    template : `
      <h1>{{title}}</h1>
      <h2>Toolage</h2>
      <p>Tools:</p>
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let tool of tools">
          {{ tool.theTile }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    `
})
export class Toolage {

    private tools:ToolButtonComponent[] = [ 
        new ToolButtonComponent("tool button"), 
        new FunButtonComponent('fun button'), 
        new CoolButtonComponent("fa-eraser")
    ];

    public getTools():ToolButtonComponent[] {

        return this.tools;

    }// end function

}// end class


@Component({
  selector: 'app-tool-button',
  template: `
    <button>{{ theTile }}</button>
  `
})
export class ToolButtonComponent implements OnInit {

    public theTile:string;

    public constructor(theTile:string) {

        this.theTile = theTile;

    }// end constructor

}// end class


export class FunButtonComponent extends ToolButtonComponent {

    public constructor(theTile:string) {

        super(theTile);

    }// end constructor

}// end class


export class CoolButtonComponent extends ToolButtonComponent {

    public constructor(theTile:string) {

        super(theTile);

    }// end constructor

}// end class
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I'm a newbie.  It's confusing since TypeScript automatically defines members from the constructor, if I am correct.

Comment: @ATL_DEV Ah I see, to do that you need to add an access modifier(public, private etc) before the parameter like this `constructor(public theTile:string) {}`.

Comment: @ATL_DEV btw what exactly are you trying to achieve with this application because I feel like this may not be the correct(or at least besy) way to go about it.

Comment: Nope.  You got it right.  This Angular stuff is cool in one way and needlessly complex in another way.  It feels like a really coarse API that replumbs CSS/HTML to do what it wants.  Also, TypeScript throws some of its own awkward language constructs like declaring properties from a constructor.